# What's the current state of navigateToUrl and popup blockers

Tags: apache-flex, popup

Apparently there's a [problem with the `nagivateToUrl` function in Flex](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-12987), namely that it tends to get blocked by the popup blockers in some browsers. A project I've recently joined is using a workaround for Firefox using browser sniffing, but a new feature would be a lot cleaner to implement if I could drop this.

Does anyone know whether this problem still exists with current Firefox versions? What about Firefox 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting article over here : http://www.codebasement.com/2010/01/actionscript-3pop-up-blocker-ie-and-navigatetourl-wont-open/

I haven't tried it myself yet so I don't know if it actually works. The idea is to create a form in the HTML DOM (using ExternalInterface.call and an anonymous function) and make that form open the popup by submitting itself to the target URL.